# Migrating Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online) to SVN? Any way to do this?

Tags: svn, tfs, azure-devops

We have a project (per the owner) to migrate from Visual Studio Team Services (was VS/TFS Online) to a local SVN Repository.

Has anyone done this before or is there potential options.

I believe I've seen http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/ which has not seem to work with Visual Studio Team Services.

We'd like to keep history as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your TFS repository to Git repository first and then convert it to SVN. Refer to this link for details: [Migrating Repository Data from TFS to SVN with History](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/899129/Migrating-Repository-Data-from-TFS-to-SVN-with-His).

Comment: Thanks Eddie --- I will give this an attempt